# Debugging a swagger codegen error with fastapi generated openapi.json

Tags: fastapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I'm trying to generate the client for my service using the [online swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/). I've written the server in fastapi. Until a few days ago, I was able to load my openapi.json and generate the client.

I've since made a few changes to the server endpoints, and now when I try to generate the client, nothing happens on the browser. I went into F12 and see the following error:

```
Could not load content for webpack://SwaggerEditorStandalonePreset/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)
```

I'm very new to swagger and to generating clients. How should I go about debugging this error?

As a first step, I used an online API validator to ensure that my openapi.json file was valid.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realized that the name of a parameter to an endpoint was the same as a class name (case insensitive). Renaming one of them enabled me to generate the python client.